How to use `qt_target_qml_sources` from a subdirectory of `qt_add_qml_module` folder?
I am trying to use qt_add_qml_module command while placing QML sources in a sub-folder with its own CMakeLists file. In the view-folders CMakeLists:
qt_add_library(MainModule STATIC)
qt_add_qml_module(MainModule
    URI main_module
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES
        Main_Page.qml
)
add_subdirectory(submodule)

In the sub-folders CMakeLists:
qt_target_qml_sources(MainModule
    QML_FILES
        Sub_Page.qml
)

However, it seems like I am missing something as the build is unsuccessful (GCC compiler) given the following error.
<project_folder>\modularMinQml\min_qml_module\build\Desktop_Qt_6_6_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\view\submodule\.rcc\qmlcache\MainModule_Sub_Page_qml.cpp:-1: error: <project_folder>/modularMinQml/min_qml_module/build/Desktop_Qt_6_6_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/view/submodule/.rcc/qmlcache/MainModule_Sub_Page_qml.cpp: No such file or directory

It worth noting that the project runs smoothly with qt_target_qml_sources written in the same CMakeLists as qt_add_qml_module.
A minimal project regarding the problem is available at:
minimal_qml_module where the structure tree is as follows
D:.
│   CMakeLists.txt
│
├───main
│       CMakeLists.txt
│       header.h
│       main.cpp
│
└───view
    │   CMakeLists.txt
    │   Main_Page.qml
    │
    └───submodule
            CMakeLists.txt
            Sub_Page.qml

Any help would be appreciated.

The generated .cpp files are the responsibility of CACHEGEN. So all you need to do is specifying NO_CACHEGEN and it goes well
The result

Thanks. It totally worked. Though, could you please add a more comprehensive explanation to enlighten how stopping the QML compiler from generating .cpp files make it true?
